# PowerPoint 2007: Paragraph and character styles?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint

Does PowerPoint 2007 have support for paragraph and character styles (as opposed to formatting and reformatting everything manually)?

I know you can set some styles in the Slide Master view, but I haven't been able to find any interface for managing text styles independently of the slide master.

To clarify: I'm wondering if there's a style manager like the ones in in MS Word and in all the OpenOffice applications.

Comment: And to answer the other question, yes, OpenOffice and its derivatives have a style manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the Font Theme editor the answer is No. The Slide Master is probably the easiest way to do this.

(I have just confirmed this in both Powerpoint 2007 and Powerpoint 2010TC)

Answer (score 1):

Another "fix": Create text placeholders for any master slides where you will be highlighting. Format these placeholder fonts with whatever style and color of glow you choose. I have three placeholders at the bottom of my masters; 1 for gray glow/highlight 36pt Times Roman, one for yellow 36pt Times Roman and one for yellow 44pt Times Roman. Once back in Normal edit mode, and I want to highlight text, I right click on the formatted placeholder, select the Format Painter and apply the chosen format to whatever text I want.
I recommend you replace the default placeholder text with a small description of the style you've created e.g. "36pt", 44pt etc.